# Preferences in ICS

Tags: android

I don't own any Ice Cream Sandwich device, and right now I'm developing apps using the menu button to show option menu. If there's no menu button in some ICS devices (like Galaxy Nexus) how could the menu be called? Which is the pattern to follow in that cases?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ICS shows a menu button in the bottom bar if your app requires that. Your app will work without modifications.

You could have a look at ActionBar though. Either through the compatibility package or via [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)